# How to get the maximum value from list type values in a column and create new column with maximum value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I have the below dataframe:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    d = {'Cell':['A','B','C','D','E'],'D1':[5, 2, 2, 6,6], 'D2':[np.nan, 5, 6, np.nan,3], 'D3':[7,np.nan, 5, 5,np.nan], 'D6':[17, 3, np.nan,np.nan,2],'diff%':[np.nan,[40],[16.67],[16.67,50],[50,33,24]]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)

    Cell  D1   D2   D3    D6         diff%
0    A   5  NaN  7.0  17.0           NaN
1    B   2  5.0  NaN   3.0          [40]
2    C   2  6.0  5.0   NaN       [16.67]
3    D   6  NaN  5.0   NaN   [16.67, 50]
4    E   6  3.0  NaN   2.0  [50, 33, 24]
```

1. I want to create a new column(max_diff%) with maximum value in the list type column(diff%)

Below is the dataframe that I want:

```
    Cell  D1   D2   D3    D6         diff% max_diff%
0    A   5  NaN  7.0  17.0           NaN   NaN
1    B   2  5.0  NaN   3.0          [40]   40
2    C   2  6.0  5.0   NaN       [16.67]   16.67
3    D   6  NaN  5.0   NaN   [16.67, 50]   50
4    E   6  3.0  NaN   2.0  [50, 33, 24]]  50
```

Please let me know any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `numpy.max` to the needed column:

```
df['max_diff%'] = df['diff%'].apply(np.max)
print(df)
```

---

```
  Cell  D1   D2   D3    D6         diff%  max_diff%
0    A   5  NaN  7.0  17.0           NaN        NaN
1    B   2  5.0  NaN   3.0          [40]      40.00
2    C   2  6.0  5.0   NaN       [16.67]      16.67
3    D   6  NaN  5.0   NaN   [16.67, 50]      50.00
4    E   6  3.0  NaN   2.0  [50, 33, 24]      50.00
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could also use the faster Pandas `agg` function

```py
import numpy as np

df['max_diff%'] = df.agg({'diff%':lambda x: np.max(x)})

print(df)
```

```
  Cell  D1   D2   D3    D6         diff%  max_diff%
0    A   5  NaN  7.0  17.0           NaN        NaN
1    B   2  5.0  NaN   3.0          [40]      40.00
2    C   2  6.0  5.0   NaN       [16.67]      16.67
3    D   6  NaN  5.0   NaN   [16.67, 50]      50.00
4    E   6  3.0  NaN   2.0  [50, 33, 24]      50.00
```